# how to use SED to replace comments within a comments section

Tags: sed, block-comment

Assume that I have a file that starts with the following

```
    /*********************************************************
    blah blah blah
    blah blah blah
    blah blah blah
    *********************************************************/
    Actual code follows here
    code 
    code 
    code
```

The command I used:

```
    sed -i 's/(/*).*(*/)/\1 newcomment \2/1' file
```

but I received the error message

```
    sed: -e expression #1, char 14: unknown option to `s'
```

p.s. my question is ... how can i  REPLACE the "blah blah blah..." comments with other bloah bloah bloah comments ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's more easily done with `perl`:

```
perl -0777 -pi -e 's{/\*.*?\*/}{/* new comment */}s' file.c
```

Would replace the first occurrence of `/*...*/` with the new comment.

`sed` processes the text one line at a time, so you can't match a multi-line text, unless you do add the other lines to the pattern space (or you use `-z` with recent versions of GUN `sed`):

```
sed -zi 's|/\*.*\*/|/* new comment */|' file.c
```

Or portably (assuming short files):

```
sed -e :1 -e '$!{N;b1' -e '}' -e 's|/\*.*\*/|/* new comment */|' file.c
```

However note that since `sed` doesn't support the `*?` non-greedy operator of `perl`, that means that it will match from the first occurrence of `/*` to the *last* occurrence of `*/`, so it would replace `/* comment 1 */ some C code /* comment 2 */` with `/* new comment */`.

Doing it with `sed` is possible but more painful. See [here](/a/297378) for an example (that also takes care of avoiding `/*` occurrences inside `"strings"` and a few other caveats).

A simplified solution that would be the equivalent of that `perl` one would be something like:

```
sed '
  # load the whole file into the pattern space
  :1
  $!{
    N;b1
  }
  s/_/_u/g;s/>/_c/g; # use _ as an escape character to escape
                     # the > we will be using in place of */
  s|\*/|>|g; # replace */ with >
  s|/\*[^>]*>|/* new comment */|
  s|>|*/|g; # undo the replacement and escaping
  s/>/_c/g;s/_u/_/g' file.c
```

With GNU `awk`, you could do:

```
awk -v RS='\\*/' '
  !found && sub(/\/\*.*/, "/* new comment ") {found = 1}
  {printf "%s", $0 RT}' file.c
```

Comment: i think ur answer might be more correct but I don't use perl so, can u you think of a way to use SED or AWK ... the previous answer provided for SED actually DOES NOT REPLACE THE OLD COMMENT .... MERELY ADDS THE NEW COMMENT

Comment: wow so, genuinely it would mean that I cannot control whether this is the first comment only ? Assuming there are multiple comments in the c code file .... and I just want to REPLACE THE FIRST COMMENT WHICH STRETECHES OVER MULTIPLE LINES ..... what do I do with sed ?

Comment: @Chan, see edit.

Comment: @stepahne can u please recommend me some source to educate myself. this code is rather long and confusing for a newbie like myself. I thoroughly appreciate it. One final remark , regarding to the simplified Perl version. how do I store a temp original file and make the difference between files visible aka printable using diff

Comment: final question. how do i include multi line comment as newcomment ?  if i am using the perl function are there any abbreviations ?

Answer (score 1):

Escape the brackets and slashes

```
 sed -i 's/\(\/*\).*\(*\/\)/\1 newcomment \2/1' file
```

Comment: I receive the followin error message for this:

Comment: sed: -e expression #1, char 15: unknown option to `s'

Comment: sorry, updated.

Comment: same error ?!  I receive

Comment: what is wrong with my approach; could u illustrate please ?

Comment: actually wait ... this still doesn't solve the problem ... it doesn't REPLACE THE PREVIOUS COMMENT ...

Comment: `s/blah/bloah/g` I don't understand your goal

Comment: I would like to replace the entire old comment by a new comment ..... it's whatever is included between /***** xxxxxxxx zzzzzz ddddd *****\ i want to be replaced /**** mynewcoments  ****\